# C# LINQ behavior

Tags: c#, linq

[image][image][image]I came across a case where I was executing below code and result was eye opening for me.

When I decompiled above code in ILSPY tool, there is a new object for displayType created before equality check. Why is it necessary? what does it accomplish by this?

```
public override bool CheckSupport(DisplayType displayType)
{
     return Displays.Any(x => x.DisplayType == displayType);
}
```

Comment: It might be useful to include the IL code that you're talking about.

Comment: the `x => ...` is an anonymous method. The compiler creates a class that contains that method for you.

Comment: What is `DisplayType`? A class or struct?

Comment: You should also include the result and what you expected when the result was "eye opening for you".

Comment: Downvoters, this is an interesting question. The compiler *does* generate an extra class, it's not `DisplayType` though.

Comment: it's a class. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: When I tried this code [in Sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLRWQTwHYGNXIxJQC2yANACYgDUAPgAIAMABAwIwDcAsAFDNt2AOgAyAS2wBHHrz4MAzGwBMLACJjkABwA2UTABVMmiHwDefAL585ihivVbdmM3xZu2ihzr2Hjajd4GRhAspgDmEDCcyJGcVrzxNsosAMKhru4K/o56ANoAutmByAC82BAA7kVOuUz5Mu4sGW5ZwAD2bdqpABYQuADWAMpwmpptCDAAFF5OviGUAbPBAJQuvI1sAOzVeshCAILYmJMAHiwlAHwsJ0IzPsHnJSwLOUHGyzLxFkA) the generated code does *NOT* include an extra class for DisplayType. It generates a new class that tests `x => x.DisplayType == displayType` which is aptly named .... <>c__DisplayClass1_0

Comment: @vikashsinha you'll have to provide types for `DisplayType` and Displays, but my guess is you mistook the lambda type for `DisplayType`

Comment: DisplayType is just a placeholder in my code.

Comment: As I already said the `DisplyClass1`-class is created by the compiler and contains your check, which is a method named `b__0`.

Comment: Please don´t post images of source-code, as it´s hard to try it out in a debugegr in order to reproduce your issue. Instead post the *actual* code.

Comment: lol @ the close reason ....

Comment: @vikashsinha I'll repeat it too: Please don't post images of your source code. Actual code can be copied into Sharplab or Linqpad, compiled and tests. Images mean we'll have to type it ourselves. Not nice

Comment: @HimBromBeere, the link which you posted has answer t o my question. From next time, I will post the codes. I didn't know that earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your lambda “captures” a variable from the function (the function parameter). Because that lambda might get invoked after the function returns (it won’t here, but the compiler doesn’t know that), it creates a helper class that will hold a reference to it so that the lambda code can reference that safely.

Comment: Why is it down-voted?

Comment: May be because you posted screenshots instead of pasting code here

Answer (score 2):

It's not a new instance of `DisplayType` or `Display`. It's the object that represents the lambda expression.

When I tried this code in [SharpLab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLRWQTwHYGNXIxJQC2yANACYgDUAPgAIAMABAwIwDcAsAFDNt2AOgAyAS2wBHHrz4t5bAMxsATCwAiY5AAcANlEwAVTNohyFAb3PyAvn2tLVGrXoMOrvBV8ead+oyYQzn4GxqYsFgDmEDCcyDGcdp4KSQ4MygxqAMIRDl7pwa6YANoAuoX+yAC82BAA7hUGxUylMnkKBcAA9l26LFkAFhC4ANYAynDa2l0IMAAUvkVhQZQu/ssAlO3yHt578gwA7I2YyEIAgtiYcwAeLFUAfCw3QovrgfdVLKshAaYbMn2LCSXhsQA) :

```
public class DisplayType
{
}

public class Display
{
    public DisplayType DisplayType {get;set;}
}

public class C {
    public Display[] Displays=new Display[0];

    public bool CheckSupport(DisplayType displayType)
    {
         return Displays.Any(x => x.DisplayType == displayType);
    }
}
```

The compiler-generated code for class C looked like this:

```
public class C
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass1_0
    {
        public DisplayType displayType;

        internal bool <CheckSupport>b__0(Display x)
        {
            return x.DisplayType == displayType;
        }
    }

    public Display[] Displays = new Display[0];

    public bool CheckSupport(DisplayType displayType)
    {
        <>c__DisplayClass1_0 <>c__DisplayClass1_ = new <>c__DisplayClass1_0();
        <>c__DisplayClass1_.displayType = displayType;
        return Displays.Any(<>c__DisplayClass1_.<CheckSupport>b__0);
    }
}
```

`<>c__DisplayClass1_` is a compiler generated class whose `<CheckSupport>b__0` method implements the predicate passed to `Any`.

```
    private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass1_0
    {
        public DisplayType displayType;

        internal bool <CheckSupport>b__0(Display x)
        {
            return x.DisplayType == displayType;
        }
    }
```

The statement :

```
<>c__DisplayClass1_.displayType = displayType;
```

Captures the value of `displayType` for use by the lambda.

Comment: you never explained *why*

Comment: @SelmanGenç I *did* in the very first line. That's what the compiler generats for a lambda. `It's not a new instance of DisplayType or Display. It's the object that represents the lambda expression.`

Comment: the OP never claimed it's an instance of display type. read the question again

Comment: @SelmanGenç "there is a new object for displayType created" Pretty sounds like that to me.

Comment: "for displayType" is not "an instance of displayType"